# Outputs onto same line?

Tags: java, output

I'm having problem with outputting two separate questions. 
The code is:

```
System.out.println("Please enter full name: ");

String name = keyboard.nextLine();

while (name.length() >= 21) 
{
    System.out.println("Name is invalid, please re enter:");
    name = keyboard.nextLine();
}


System.out.println("Please enter reference number: ");
String reference = keyboard.nextLine();

while (reference.length() > 6) {
    System.out.println("Refrence incorrect, please re enter");
    reference = keyboard.nextLine();
}
while (!reference.matches("(?i)[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}[A-Z]")) {
    System.out.println("Reference is incorrect, please re-enter:");
    reference = keyboard.nextLine();
```

however what is being output resembles:

```
Please enter full name:

Please enter reference number:
```

with no room for me to input the name or reference. Even when i do, it asks for the reference again. Can anybody spot any problems in my code? (I'm a beginner if you couldn't tell my the un elegant coding haha)

the code that came before this is:

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please select from the following options:");
    System.out.println("1. Enter new Policy");
    System.out.println("2. Display summary of policies");
    System.out.println("3. Display summary of policies for selected month");
    System.out.println("4. Find and display Policy");
    System.out.println("0. Exit");
    int option = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (option == 1) {
        System.out.println("Please enter full name: ");
```

...

Comment: Yes i have, but that just prints it to one line instead. :(

Comment: Can you post all the code is before of this?

Comment: posted it in the original question :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you call

```
int option = keyboard.nextInt();
```

It doesn't read the last newline character, you could solve this by calling

```
int option = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
```

`nextLine()` will also consume the newline character, but it will return a `String`, so you need to parse it as an `Integer`.

**Edit:**

If the input (in `nextInter`) is not an Integer, you will get an `NumberFormatException`. To handle this you must use a `try-catch` clause:

```
int option;
try {
    option = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: when i put the second part in about the try catch clause, then the:
if (option == 1)
doesn't work? 
Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Why it doesn't work? Do you get an error? Try printing `option` so you  know what value is.

Comment: Sorry my fault, it must be `keyboard.nextLine()`, not `input.nextLine()`. Edited.

Comment: no, it just doesnt recognise that they have the same value. I fixed it by declaring option at the start of the code, but not sure if that was the best possible way?

Comment: It's an scope issue, since `option` was declared inside the `try-block` you couldn't use it after the block. Try reading about **scopes** in Java.